# iPhone ignoring media query

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm working on a responsive, Bootstrap 3-based design.  When I resize the browser window on my desktop, everything behaves as expected, but when I went to look at it on my iPhone it doesn't collapse the menu as it should, among other things.

http://www.craftonhills.edu/Testing/ksimonso/Mobile_Site_Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the viewport tag to your header:

**HTML**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) within your `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```